# Why is the determinant of an orthogonal matrix always $1 or -1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, determinant

I was asked to find the value of $|A|$ for any orthogonal matrix
to do this, I considered the simplest orthogonal matrix

$$n
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which gives

$|A|=n$, as $ n|I|=n $
however, my book solves this by using the fact that $AA^T=I$
which gives $|A|= 1 or -1 $

why is my answer wrong?

Comment: That's not orthogonal unless $n^2 = 1$.

Comment: The matrix you have written is not orthogonal (unless $n=\pm 1$), and its determinant is $n^2$, not $n$.

Comment: but isn't the identity matrix orthogonal?

Comment: and so a scalar operation on the orthogonal matrix should mean it's still orthogonal, right?

Comment: Yes. No.........

Comment: why is that? I've always understood multiplying a matrix by a scalar as simply a scaling operation, why is that wrong?

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever It is true that the matrix $nI$ has *orthogonal* columns, but (perhaps confusingly) an *orthogonal* matrix is required to have *orthonormal* columns, i.e. orthogonal columns of length 1.

Comment: oh, I see, @BenGrossmann, thanks!

Comment: IF the matrix are over the real numbers $\pm1$ are the only options for determinants of orthogonal matrices (orthogonal columns with unit norms). If the matrices are over the complex numbers, in which case $A^*A=I$, then any number in the unit circle $|z|=1$ is an option of determinant of $A$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Such matrices are usually called "unitary", not "orthogonal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, the fact that the determinant of an orthogonal matrix $A$ is $\pm1$ comes from the fact that $AA^T = I$ and $\det A = \det A^T$.  You get $\det(A)^2 = \det(I) = 1$, so $\det A = \pm 1$.

Scaling a matrix by a constant does not usually preserve orthogonality. This is because the transpose of $\alpha A$ is $\alpha A^T$ So if $A$ is orthogonal, $(\alpha A)(\alpha A)^T = \alpha^2 AA^T = \alpha^2 I$.

Good comment from Ben Grossman above: an orthogonal matrix is characterized by *orthonormal* columns, not just orthogonal columns. That might be the source of the confusion.

Also: orthogonal matrices preserve distance. Scaling usually doesn't.

Comment: I see, thanks, so basically, an orthogonal matrix is one that ensures  that the modulus of the magnitude of the basis vectors obtained is always 1, right?

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever I think it's more intuitive to say that orthogonal matrices represent linear isometries, meaning they preserve distances. It's an easy geometric way to see why they're so useful.